# Como guardar un arreglo bidimensional en uno unidimensional

Tags: java

Quiero guardar un arreglo bidimensional en uno unidimensional que tendra una acumulacion de datos, en dias y carreras, entonces quiero guardar este en uno unidimensional el cual sera la suma de las veces que escogieron una carrera en el total de dias, este arreglo por ejemplo tendra que en un total de 5 dias se ecogio una carrera 6 veces, entonces eso es lo que quiero guardar en el arreglo unidimensional

```
import java.io.*;
class Carrera{
   public static void main(String arg[])
   {
       int acum[][]=new int[5][6];
       String carrera[]=new String[6];
       int total=Carrera.calcularTotal(acum);
       carrera=Carrera.leerCarrera();
      acum=Carrera.leerDia(carrera); 
      int mayor=Carrera.numeroMayor(carrera,acum); 

       Carrera.imprimirResultado(carrera,total,mayor); 
   }
   public static String[] leerCarrera()
   {
      String carrera[]=new String[6];
         carrera[0]="IMA";
         carrera[1]="IIS";
         carrera[2]="ITC";
         carrera[3]="ITR";
         carrera[4]="IMT";
         carrera[5]="IDA";

         return carrera;
   }


   public static int[][] leerDia(String carrera[])
   {

      int acum[][]=new int[5][6];
      byte deci=0;
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
         do{
         System.out.println(" Para dia "+(i+1)+ " Ingrese 6 para "+carrera[5]+" 5 para "+carrera[4]+" 4 para "+carrera[3]+" 3 para "+carrera[2]+" 2 para "+carrera[1]+" 1 para "+carrera[0]+" y 0 cuando no quiera agregar mas carreras");
                  deci=Lectura.readByte();
                  switch(deci)
         {
            case 1:
            acum[i][0]+=1;
            break;
            case 2:
            acum[i][1]+=1;
            break;
            case 3:
            acum[i][2]+=1;
            break;
           case 4:
           acum[i][3]+=1;
           break;
           case 5:
           acum[i][4]+=1;
           break;
           case 6:
           acum[i][5]+=1;
         }
         }while (deci!=0);
      }
      return acum;
   }

   public static int calcularTotal(int acum[][])
   {  
      int total=0;

      for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
                  total+=acum[i][j];}


      return total;
    }

    public static int numeroMayor (String carrera[], int acum[][])
    {
      int mayor=0;
      for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
      {
         int acumCarrera[]=new int[6];
             acumCarrera[i]=acumCarrera[i]+acum[j][i];} 

         for(int k=1;k<6;k++)
         {int comparar=acumCarrera[0];
          if (comparar<acumCarrera[k])
               {comparar=acumCarrera[k];
                mayor=k;}
         }
       }
       return mayor;
     }



    public static void imprimirResultado(String carrera[],int total, int mayor)
    {
      System.out.println("La carrera con mayor demanda es "+carrera[mayor]);
      System.out.println("El total de alumnos es de: "+total);
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

La mejor opción, sería utilizar un objeto **Collection**, en concreto cualquier que herede de **List**, como **ArrayList**, pero visto que pides exclusivamente array este sería mi método aplicado para obtenerlo.

```
Object[] getUnidimensionalArrayFromMultidimensional(Object[][] matrix, int row) {
     Object[] vector = new Object[matrix.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
         vector[i] = matrix[i][row];
     }
     return vector;
}
```